# Asynchronous accessor

Tags: architecture, asynchronous, functional-programming

**Question**: What techniques can be used to implement a function which returns a value asynchronously?

Invalid code of desired effect (in ActionScript... excuse Prettify):

```
public function get item() : InventoryItem {
    return InventoryItem.find(this.id);
}

public class InventoryItem {
    public static function find(id : int) : InventoryItem {
        var statement:SQLStatement = statementCreator.create('FIND_BY_ID');
        statement.parameters['@id'] = id.toString();
        statement.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, 
            function (event : SQLEvent) : InventoryItem {
                // find returns from here
                return (event.target as SQLStatement).getResult().data[0] as InventoryItem;
            });
        statement.execute();
    }
}
```

**Background**: I'm currently using Flex and a constant problem turns up: the need to have asynchronous functions or even callbacks return a value to an accessor function or any other function which uses the return value from another function.

In Flex this seems impossible to implement.  I've been looking at continuations, mutexes, concurrent programming, trying to find an equivalent to "yield" in ActionScript to see if coroutines could be used, but to absolutely no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to a continuation passing style and use `setTimeout`.

Comment: Yet the return value for the callback never actually gets used anywhere, even using this method.  How to do this?